# DEM classified using SAGA GIS and conversion to point shape

Tags: saga, terrain

I have converted DEM to terrain specific points i.e. peaks, pits, saddle points etc. with SAGA GIS using surface specific points tools. The output is showing values as 1, 7, 9 -1 etc; with different colors.

I want to convert to point shape values have attribute values with 1, 7, 9, -1.

How to do in SAGA GIS?

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use either **Add Grid Values to Points** or **Grid Values to Points** tool. They are under "Shapes- Grid" of Tools manager. (see below image, from SAGA 2.1.2)

If you already have a Point Shapefile which represents your points of interest (from where you want to extract the cell value), please use 'Add Grid Values to Points' tool.

If not, 'Grid Values to Points' will create a new Shapefile for you with an attribute column named after the raster filename, in which the extracted cell-values. You would prefer to choose Type: nodes, which produces point Shapefile, every cell is represented by a point - "node". (Type: cells will give you something grid-like.)

[image]